# Mixamo Models not Importing Correctly in Unity

Tags: unity, models, importing

Mixamo (now Adobe Mixamo) allows us to choose character and then animations from its website from free samples. I have done one simple animation and added the model to Unity. The animation works fine but the model is very changed once being imported, have a look here.

[image]

I am using following import settings,

Format: Fbx for Unity

Skin: With Skin

FPS: 30

Keyframe Reduction: Uniform

I tried "Fbx" format only too, but no luck.I also applied "humanoid" in rigging, but I think it is not relevant here. Since I am not good with modeling that is why I am using this service, and I have no idea how to tackle this. Once it did worked well, but unfortunately I could not remember how, so I am stuck again.

Comment: This looks like inverted normals. Is there an option for that somewhere? (In Mixamo as well as Unity). Also, check the material in Unity. It might be set to Transparent/Bumped Diffuse. Switch that to a non-transparent one

Comment: You may want to  add this as answer since it solved the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like inverted normals. Is there an option for that somewhere? (In Mixamo as well as Unity). Also, check the material in Unity. It might be set to Transparent/Bumped Diffuse. Switch that to a non-transparent one

Comment: Right, set Material type to Legacy/Diffuse or Mobile/Diffuse and now works perfect. Thanks.